# Is there a way to add [user:validate-url] link to a Simplenews newsletter on a drupal7 site?

Tags: 7, emails

I want to send a newsletter only to the users that haven't activated their accounts and persuade them to activate their accounts.
Is there a way to personalize the link they need to click and give everyone this link [user:validate-url] that sends each user at their account activation page?